# Como retornar os dados de um select no sqlite3 como dicionários ao invés de tuplas em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Estou usando o sqlite3 para gravar alguns dados. Porém, por padrão, quando é feito um select, ele retorna as informações como uma lista de tuplas, que é consideravelmente mais difícil de trabalhar do que se fossem dicionários. Exemplo:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> bd = sqlite3.connect('python.db')
>>> cursor = bd.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE livro (titulo text, autor text)')
>>> cursor.execute('INSERT INTO livro VALUES (?, ?)', ('Manoel', 'Minha história'))
>>> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM livro')
>>> livros = cursor.fetchall()
>>> livros
[('Manoel', 'Minha história')]
```

A solução mais óbvia que consigo pensar seria:

```
>>> lista_livros = []
>>> for livro in livros:
>>>     d = {'autor': livro[0], 'titulo': livro[1],}
>>>     lista_livros.append(d)
```

Porém dessa maneira o código fica consideravelmente grande quando existem muitas colunas. E dessa maneira, toda vez que houver alguma alteração nas colunas, seria necessário alterar o código também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível atingir este resultado alterando o atributo [row_factory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory) do cursor.

Este atributo deve receber um callable, que aceite como argumentos o cursor e os registros(rows), como neste exemplo adaptada da documentação:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> 
>>> def dict_factory(cursor, row):
...     d = {}
...     for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
...         d[col[0]] = row[idx]
...     return d
... 
>>> bd = sqlite3.connect('python.db')
>>> cursor = bd.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE livro (titulo text, autor text)')
>>> cursor.execute('INSERT INTO livro VALUES (?, ?)', ('Manoel', 'Minha história'))
>>> cursor.row_factory = dict_factory
>>> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM livro')
>>> livros = cursor.fetchall()
>>> livros
[{'titulo': 'Manoel', 'autor': 'Minha história'}]
>>> livros[0]['titulo']
'Manoel'
```

A documentação cita também que em casos onde é necessário desempenho pode ser utilizado o callable [sqlite3.Row](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row), que possui funções como mapeamento pelo nome da coluna, indexação, iteração, teste de igualdade e suporta o método len() que retorna a quantidade total de registros(rows).

Demonstração de utilização do sqlite3.Row retirado da documentação:

```
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute('''create table stocks (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')
>>> c.execute("""insert into stocks values ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)""")
>>> conn.commit()
>>> c.close()

>>> conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute('select * from stocks')
>>> r = c.fetchone()
>>> type(r)
<class 'sqlite3.Row'>
>>> tuple(r)
('2006-01-05', 'BUY', 'RHAT', 100.0, 35.14)
>>> len(r)
5
>>> r[2]
'RHAT'
>>> r.keys()
['date', 'trans', 'symbol', 'qty', 'price']
>>> r['qty']
100.0
>>> for member in r:
...     print(member)
...
2006-01-05
BUY
RHAT
100.0
35.14
```

Comment: É interessante notar que outros conectores À DBs, como os conectores à MySQL e Postgres possuem o "DictCursor" que já faz o que é requisitado - no entanto para o sqlite3 ele não está disponível.